# Does Google Custom Search help with SEO?

Tags: seo, google-programmable-search-engine

When adding a Google Custom Search box to my site, does that help SEO, and does it influence regular Google web results? If not, does it provide me with data to help me optimize my website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Google custom search will not affect your pages' rankings. If you're looking for data that will help optimize your website sign up for a [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) account. It offers a bunch of useful information for how Google sees your website and even allows Google to communicate problems to you.

Comment: Google Webmaster Tools and Bing Webmaster Tools are good sites with tools to show you how the search engines see your site. Some HTML, Sitemap, and robots.txt errors will be displayed if any. They'll also make vague suggestions on how to improve your site. But having well optimized content (for humans) is your best bet for on site optimization. Offsite getting links for relevant authoritive sites will help you rank higher. Google custom search has nothing to do with how you rank it's just an easy way to search your own sites content.

Answer (score 4):

it seems that this may have an impact, as explained here:
[Is Google Custom Search Influencing Google Web Search?](http://www.seobythesea.com/2010/10/is-google-custom-search-influencing-google-web-search/)

Answer (score -1):

There are many articles that support the rumor of Google custom search engine helps your SEO. I am not sure if it doesnt make any difference on the SEO or if it improves the revenue but its for sure its the best promo message for Google custom search. 
If there is anyone who has checked seo impact from google custom search usage in his site, please share your story :)